# I want to create an automation with anki and my cloudserver and ChatGPT

Tags: python, php, cron

I'm currently trying to play around with my cloud server and set up a personal project. I want to create a cron job that imports newly added data from the database into Anki every evening at 9 PM.

Locally, this is not a problem with AnkiConnect, but on the cloud server, it's a huge challenge. I want to achieve a scenario where, for example, I create new questions using ChatGPT and then save them to the database (which I can easily do). Then, the cron job I've built should check every evening if there are any questions in the database with the status "in_anki = false". If there are, it should add them (as I mentioned, everything works fine locally).

However, my problem is that I don't have a graphical user interface (GUI). I can open the program, and Anki Connect is also installed in the addons21 folder on the server. But there are two issues: First, Anki needs to be running, which seems to work with the command:
xvfb-run -a --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" anki

Using xvfb, I can see that Anki is running. I have also loaded the prefs21 onto the server (from my Windows PC) to have my login details there. I don't know how to install a GUI on a cloud server and, secondly, whether I can do this without violating any guidelines or policies. I'm at a loss, and I would greatly appreciate your help!

Here is my code:

```
// error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function request($action, $params=array()) {
    $data = array(
        'action' => $action,
        'params' => $params,
        'version' => 6
    );
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/json",
            'content' => json_encode($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8765', false, $context);
    
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception('Failed to connect to AnkiConnect');
    }
    
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    
    if (isset($result['error'])) {
        throw new Exception('AnkiConnect returned an error: ' . $result['error']);
    }
    
    return $result['result'];
}

$deckName = 'TestDeck';
$modelName = 'Basic';
$front = 'Front content';
$back = 'Back content';
request('createDeck', array('deck' => $deckName));
request('addNote', array(
    'note' => array(
        'deckName' => $deckName,
        'modelName' => $modelName,
        'fields' => array(
            'Front' => $front,
            'Back' => $back,
        )
    )
));
```

And that is what i get as error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost:8765): Failed to open stream: Connection refused in /var/www/html/db/mail.php on line 22
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Failed to connect to AnkiConnect in /var/www/html/db/mail.php:25 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/db/mail.php(41): request() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/db/mail.php on line 25

Comment: The server actively refused the connection. Either your hostname/port are incorrect, or the service is not running, or not listening on the address/port that you think it is, or there is a firewall blocking you.

Comment: Is the question about the errors you get, the _"I don't know how to install a GUI on a cloud server"_ or _"whether I can do this without violating any guidelines or policies"_? Please edit the question to contain one single clear answerable on-topic question (we can't help with guidelines/policies, for example) and remove anything that's not relevant to that specific issue.